# Distributing 5 unique gifts to four friends.

Tags: combinatorics

I am having trouble with the following problem: I have four friends. I am going to give each of them a gift. My choices of gifts are: A red car, a red boat, a green tree, a brown dog, or a grey laptop.

a) How many ways are there to give them these gifts? (More than one can receive the same gift)

b) How many ways are there to give them these gifts, assuming that Leonard and Arthur must receive the same gift?

c) How many ways are there to give them these gifts, assuming that Leonard and Arthur must not receive the same gift?

d) How many ways are there to give them these gifts, assuming that Leonard and Arthur must not receive the same color gift?

Comment: Is this homework? Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: I began on part a by diagramming out the possibilities when the first friend gets a red car and not sure where to go next, and not sure how to use combinations rather than brute force to find the possibilities.

Comment: Why don't you try to learn some basic combinatorics first? It would solve all similar future problems.

Answer (score 0):

The "objects in boxed" point of view is useful here. in a) you have four objects and in b) you have three. Consider each gift a box and each friend an object and then try to find in how many different ways you can place them. For the latter two questions you may want to consider using inclusion/exclusion.

Good luck!