# Ways to give four people five gifts

Tags: combinatorics

> I have four friends named Leonard, Arthur, Julius and Herbert. I am going to give each of them a gift. My choices of gifts are: a red car, a red boat, a green tree, a brown dog, or a grey laptop.
>
> a) How many ways are there to give them these gifts? (More than one can receive the same gift)

I'm thinking, $5^4=625$, because each brother can can receive any of the gifts.

> b) How many ways are there to give them these gifts, assuming that Leonard and Arthur must receive the same gift?

$5 \times 1\times 5\times 5=125$ Leo can receive any of the 5 gifts, in order for Arthur to get the exact same gift as Leo he only has 1 choice.

> c) How many ways are there to give them these gifts, assuming that Leonard and Arthur must not receive the same gift?

Can I just multiply $5 \times 4\times 5\times 5$? The first 5 represents Leo getting one of the five gifts and then the 4 represents Arthur only having 4 gift options since he can't have the same gift as Leo.

> d) How many ways are there to give them these gifts, assuming that Leonard and Arthur must not receive the same color gift?

Using the addition property I can add the ways Leo can get a red gift and the ways he can't get a red gift. So $(2 \times 3\times 5\times 5)+ (3\times 5\times 5\times 5)=525$ or Inclusion/Exclusion by doing $625-(2 \times 2\times 5\times 5)=525$

This question has been asked before, [Distributing 5 unique gifts to four friends.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527451/distributing-5-unique-gifts-to-four-friends), but I am looking for feedback on my specific solution strategies.

Comment: No partridge in a pear tree?

Comment: The last one does not look right. If they can't get the same colour, then in particular they can't get the same gift. Because there are two red gifts, the answer to d) must be less than the answer to c).

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes sense. What if I take 500, the number of ways Leo and Art get different gifts, and subtract $2\times2\times 5\times 5$ because that would represent the number of ways Art and Leo both received red gifts?

Comment: Not quite. We already subtracted same gifts, so we need to take away only the $(2)(5)(5)$  ways they can get different red gifts.

Comment: Your first expression for the last problem should be $(2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5) + (3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 5) = 450$, since choosing one of the last three gifts for Leonard permits us to choose anything but that one gift for Arthur.  Alternatively, your second expression for the last problem should be $625 - (2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 5) - (3 \times 1 \times 5 \times 5) = 450$ for the same reason.

Answer (score 3):

(a) You are correct.

(b) Correct again.

(c) Yes sir.

(d) Almost. Here's how I would do it. Treating Leonard and Arthur as a 'block' we have $5^2$ ways to arrange our $2$ remaining people. The number of permutations of our 'block' is : $3+3+4+4+4$, the first two if Leonard is red, and the last three if he is not.This gives us $5^2(2\cdot 3+3\cdot 4) = 5^2 \cdot 18=450$.

Answer (score 1):

$(a), (b),(c)$ are fine.

For (d), I would first distribute as if all colors were different,
and subtract the  case where both Leonard and Arthur choose red toys, thus

$5^2(5\times 4 -2) = 450$